# Getting error code 2200 error : 'Odbc Operation Failed' while copying data from ADF to snowflake

Tags: azure-pipelines, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

Error : Operation on target CopySnowflake failed: ErrorCode=UserErrorUnclassifiedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Odbc Operation Failed.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.IndexOutOfRangeException,Message=region_group,Source=System.Data,'

I am trying to copy data from ADF to Snowflake table. I tested the connection, it's successful. I have checked the mapping, it is correct as well. I couldn't find any solution online.

Please help me to know how to fix this issue

EDIT:
I am getting this new error now

Operation on target Copy_3j9 failed: Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=FileForbidden,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when trying to upload a blob, detailed message: topbusiness.txt,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:005f8bc6-001e-004c-32a1-b4d23d000000
Time:2021-09-28T19:46:41.7182559Z,,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,'

Kindly help me to find the fix for both

Comment: Based on the error, I'm guessing your ODBC connection is not defined correctly. If you can update your question with the ODBC configuration details (with the actual account name replaced by as masking character, obviously, for security reasons) then someone may be able to help you

Comment: Hey. I am new to snowflake so I don't know what exactly you are talking about. Where can I find the ODBC configuration ?

Comment: Presumably where you set up the connection between ADF and Snowflake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the snowflake account, I had not specified any cloud provider. I created another snowflake account by specifying Azure as the cloud provider and tried with that. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using any organizational network, please ensure to
   whitelist URLs as the connection to the Azure storage account might
   get blocked by the any organization proxy. To whitelist
   URLs*.blob.core.windows.net  on the proxy while trying to join Azure
   blob storage.
2. Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Networking -> Check Allow Access
   From (All Networks / Selected Networks) If it is "Selected Networks"
   - It means the storage account is firewall enabled. If the storage account is firewall enabled, please check the ADF is
   whitelisted to
   access.

> Because "All authorised requests must contain the Coordinated
> Universal Time (UTC) timestamp for the request," 403 is frequently
> observed when authorising using a shared key.

3. The storage services make sure a request isn't more than 15 minutes
   old when it arrives at the service. This protects against a variety
   of security threats, including replay attacks. When this check
   fails, the server issues a 403 error code (Forbidden). In this case,
   check your server's data-time.

Comment: Hey. Networking is set to All Networks. I am using Snowflake East US as cloud region and for ADF I tried using East US as well as Asia but I still get the error. Can you let me know how to fix if it's the date-time issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the problem is not with Snowflake connection, but with Azure Storage. Most probably you have the "Enable staging" option selected from the data upload activity.
Check if you have a valid connection to Azure storage (maybe your SAS key has expired), or disable this option.

Reference: [ADF Staged copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#staged-copy)

[Enable staging option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGPxU.png)